# Error: Error: File not found with singular glob:

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm getting the following error when doing a build.  The thing is it works on my other machine..  which suggests an issue with my npm / gulp config, not the codebase:

```
[10:54:27] Error: Error: File not found with singular glob: /Users/me/git/Project/app/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/Project/node_modules/gulp-useref/index.js:65:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at Through2.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at OrderedStreams.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/Project/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:140:20)
```

running `npm version` gives me:

```
{ h54s_angular_seed: '0.1.1',
  npm: '5.3.0',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '31.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '59.1',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.22.0',
  node: '8.4.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  tz: '2017b',
  unicode: '9.0',
  uv: '1.13.1',
  v8: '6.0.286.52',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Running `gulp -v` gives:

```
[11:01:07] CLI version 3.9.1
[11:01:07] Local version 3.9.1
```

Am using OSX.  How do I debug?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't installed bower!  The fix was to simply run `npm run postinstall` (this was after reinstalling npm per the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)).